# Any Upcoming SUPEE patches (1.x version)?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

To my knowledge last SUPEE update was in March/April 2016. Any ideas when to be prepared for another SUPEE update for 1.x versions?

Comment: you should ask on magento forums, next patch will be released as soon as they fix all php7 issues...

Comment: @MagenX where did you get that information? AFAIK there will be a new version 1.9.3 which is compatible to 5.6 and fixes some bugs, but PHP 7 support is not planned yet. Security patches on the other hand are not planned at long hand but come as soon as new vulnerabilities have been detected and could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The disclosure of potential security exploits to Magento platforms is not publicly available. If it were, you'd just see floods of exploits hitting your site whenever one was reported.

As such, you're not going to be made aware of fixes for these exploits until they're physically released to the market in the form of a SUPEE patch.

Essentially, no - it's unlikely you'll be able to find out when security patches will be released. Just follow the [Magento security listing pages](https://magento.com/security/patches) and keep an eye out.